# Can we control the behavior of $|f|_{p}$?

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How slow/fast can $L^p$ norm grow?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75623/how-slow-fast-can-lp-norm-grow)

Rudin asked:

Suppose $f$ is Lesbegue measurable in $(0,1)$ and not essentially bounded. Then we know $|f|_{p}\rightarrow \infty$ as $p\rightarrow \infty$. Is it true that to every positive function $\Phi$ on $(0,\infty)$ such that $\Phi(p)\rightarrow \infty$ as $p\rightarrow \infty$, then $|f|_{p}\rightarrow \infty$ but $|f|_{p}\le \Phi(p)$ for all sufficiently large $p$?

This is not possible for any $\Phi$ since $\Phi$ has to be monotone. But suppose $\Phi$ is monotone already, then can we always find $f$ such that $|f|_{p}\le \Phi(p)$? I am thinking about $\Phi=O(x^{\alpha}\log[x]^{\beta})$ type of monotone increasing function.

Comment: Are you assuming that $|f|_p$ and $\Phi(p)$ is finite?

Comment: I am implicitly assuming that. Because if that is not true, then for all $q>p$ the $q$-norm must be infinity as well. Then we only need to worry about $|f|_{?}$ when $?<p$, and the problem is substantially easier.